# Playing local video files in HTML

Tags: html, flash, flash-video

A project has various local HTML & video files for help pages. We need to be able to embed these videos in HTML pages - but because all are local files we have no server-side streaming.

Can I still just use SWFObject? Are there other well-known controls that will let us play .mp4, .swf/flv, .wmv files?

This solution is targeting HTML4 across Chrome, FF and IE (I don't know if IE6 is needed).

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your question. You use SWFObject to embed flash, but to view a FLV file you need a video player...btw, you shouldn't need server-side streaming to view flv files

Comment: @goliatone - FLV is the video format contained in SWFs, no? Anyway the situation is we want to embed a video for playback in an HTML page without any server-side tech. The video can be whatever format is needed (it'll be H264 I think). So what do we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWF can reproduce different video formats (FLV, F4V, H.264, although you need a component that handles the reproduction of the video.
For simple reproduction, you don't need a streaming server.

There are different video players available, with open source, freeware or commercial license.

You can check, both Open source:

- [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/)
- [JW Flv player (HTML5 support)](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

Answer (score 1):

The FLVPlayback component will play FLV video from the same web server the page is hosted on.  You don't need a dedicated media server to do that, unless you need more advanced streaming and/or interactive features.

Comment: Is there a ready-to-go control/SWF that can be dropped into an HTML page similar to how SWFObject works? The deal is that my client is creating HTML files (in Dreamweaver or similar) and want to be able to put videos in the pages... so far they just have links to video files which works in Chrome but not other browsers.

Comment: There are a number of free and commercial player templates you can use and configure via xml.  A simple google search for "flv player template free" should return plenty.